# How can I set a condition to navigate to different pages based on the previous page or the current page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, materialpageroute

I am working on an app and id like to ask if anyone can help me to understand how using routes I can navigate from my current screen to another page based on the previous page I navigated from. I can navigate to the page through different routes and I want to navigate to separate pages based on my previous routes

I tried using naming the routes in my MainDart and use this
bool _isfromreservation = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.name == 'reservation';
and add it to the button with an if statement conditioning if this is true.

Comment: could you tell me the whole scenario.

Comment: It's a page to provide payment method to process a transaction. so you can access the page from the profile page and then from a page after making the order to processs payment. its a page to confirm payment method. Hope it is clear now

Comment: I hope if you want to track your route screen that which screen you are come then better to use enum and using arguments to pass the enum. After that you can get your previous screen route.

Comment: alright. Thank you. Can you lead me towards something similar pls

Comment: I add a comment ..please check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this code help you ..please check this

```
enum PaymentScreenComeFrom {
  profileScreen,
  otherScreen,
}


GlobalButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => PaymentScreen(
                  paymentScreenComeFrom: PaymentScreenComeFrom.profileScreen,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          buttonText: "Profile Screen",
    )




class PaymentScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PaymentScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.paymentScreenComeFrom,
  });

  final PaymentScreenComeFrom paymentScreenComeFrom;

  @override
  State<PaymentScreen> createState() => _PaymentScreenState();
 
}

class _PaymentScreenState extends State<PaymentScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if(widget.paymentScreenComeFrom ==PaymentScreenComeFrom.profileScreen){
      
    }
    
    
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```